# How to send to data with kafkaProducer in Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am having trouble to send data to a remote Kafka cluster which should have appropriate rights.

The topic is already created on the cluster.
I have also tried to send data in bytes but still having the same error.
If you have any information it could be of great help! The error i have is on the picture provided.

[image: Kafka error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, install "pykafka" => pip install pykafka

Then launch a consumer (in a terminal for example ), run the following command :

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import threading

KAFKA_HOST = "localhost:9092" # Or the address you want

client = KafkaClient(hosts = KAFKA_HOST)
topic = client.topics["test"]

with topic.get_sync_producer() as producer:
    for i in range(10):
        message = "Test message " + str(i)
        encoded_message = message.encode("utf-8")
        producer.produce(encoded_message)
```

You will be able to see :

Test message 0

Test message 1

Test message 2

...

Test message 9

Comment: Ok thank you, but where do you specify the topic name? is it the topic you wrote that i should replace?

Comment: Oups, a line weirdly disappeared ! I've edited the code :) 
"test" is the name of your topic

Comment: It gives me the answer TopicAuthorizationFailed: Failed to auto-create topic 'b'nyt_articles'' which is the name of the topic but I know that this topic is created with rights to produce to it ..

Comment: Did your topic already exists ? 
Type "client.topics.values()" to see existing topics

Comment: It appears to be empty... But my as my connection is working (client = KafkaClient(...)) I assume I am connected well to the cluster, the topic was created remotely using command line, am i missing something?

Comment: Do you still have the command that allowed you to create the topic ?

Comment: No, but i have access to the cluster so I might be able to see the topics there

Comment: Okay, and you're sure about the IP address ? The host port ? This is the only issue I can see. Or maybe are you sure if the producer is running on your remote instance ?

Comment: Yes the port and IP addresses are ok and the producer is running.. thanks for your help I will investigate!